# "Rich in" vs. "Rich with"

Tags: differences, idioms

*The free dictionary* provides two definitions for "[rich with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rich+with)" and "[rich in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rich+in)".

- *rich with*: having a lot of something; abundant in something
- *rich in*: having valuable resources, characteristics, traditions, or history

It seems like the differences between the two definitions is rather subtle. My understanding is the following. The former case means that an *object* contains a lot of *something* (and we don't know anything about the quality of this *something*). The latter means that the *object* contains *something* which is valuable (and we don't know how many instances of this *something* our *object* contains).

Is this observation correct? Can someone clarify the difference and provide some further references?

The context of this questions is that I want to write something like "The literature is rich in/with examples".

Comment: I can't immediately think of an instance where I would you 'rich with' rather than 'rich in'. It doesn't mean 'rich with' is incorrect, just that I think 'rich in' covers instances where you could use 'rich with'. And in my view 'rich-in' does the job better.

Comment: The only instance I can think of for one of these uses is when someone is describing a breakfast cereal or such. "Rich in Iron" [link](http://www.thirdage.com/nc/fgm/breakfast-cereal-iron-800-5)

Answer (score 1):

*Rich with* does, I suggest, say something about the quality of something, and that quality is almost always positive.

> He's rich with things that money cannot buy: friendships, supportive relatives, and a spouse who encourages him each step of the way.

The above sentence uses the word *rich* in a positive way, and doing so would seem to be the norm.  I would not link the words *rich with* with negative things.

Maybe I betray a certain cultural bias in linking *rich* to only positive things, as if to be rich is necessarily a good thing. On the other hand, if irony is the reason for the link between *rich with* and the negative things, then the linkage would make sense, and to be rich is not necessarily a good thing.  For example, if the "she," above, has great wealth, but her character leaves little to be desired, I might say ironically,

> "Oh, she's rich all right.  She's rich with a nasty disposition, a passel of enemies, and a cheapness that beggars description."

"Rich in" can be used, I suggest, in many of the same ways its counterpart "rich with" can be used, as in

> The sub-Saharan country is rich in oil, manganese, and semi-precious stones,

or

> Jim is rich in kindness, generosity, and thoughtfulness,

or

> Sally is rich in friends, cheerleaders, and supporters.

In conclusion, "rich in" and "rich with" are virtually interchangeable.  As for

> The literature is rich with/in examples,

I suggest you be guided by whichever word sounds better to you, since they're both, as I said, virtually interchangeable.